# What stories of classic Doctor Who have the Doctor or the companion deconstructing the bad guy's plan before resolution?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

I'm leaving on a road trip to Sweden soon and I want to watch some Classic Doctor Who while in the car. Because there are too many episodes to watch in that short period, I want to focus on the stories where **the Doctor gives a speech or dialogue totally deconstructing the bad guy's plan: taking apart his evil plan, explaining what's wrong with it and essentially saying: "your plan won't work, here's why it won't work", either at the end of the episode or in short bursts between.** I've found that I like those stories the most, because of these reasons:

1. They nearly always end with the main monster of the week defeated and the doctor + companion triumphant;
2. They nearly always showcase the doctor at his best: cunning, smart, quick thinker and hyperanalytical.
3. In my opinion they show that no matter how good the enemy has his plan thought out, there is nearly always a way out for the heroes. It might not be realistic, but it makes for some really good viewing.

From New Who, the following stories show what I'm talking about (I can't really look up what the episode names are right now for some of them):

- **S02E01/E02**
- **S05E01**: The Eleventh Hour
- **S05 Christmas special**: A Christmas Carol
- **S07E15**: The Day of the Doctor
- **S08E05**: Time Heist
- **S08E08**
- **S08E011/E012**
- **S09E07/E08**: The Zygon Invasion/Inversion
- **S09E11**: Heaven Sent

Which of the Classic Doctor Who episodes match these criteria?-

Comment: You're not asking for much here, considering there are nearly 30 years worth of classic episodes to consider... do you have access to all the available episodes or are you restricted to the commercially available copies?

Comment: I should also point out that the question is somewhat subjective.  I'm not sure about it's adherence to scope here, but that said, I've seen every non lost episode of classic who, so I'll pick a short list for you from the list of those available.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

"Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here:
    Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: What are all the books that have X? Who wrote about topic Y?"

Comment: @PaulL I asked in chat before I created the question. Rand Al' Thor and other users have confirmed that if I define the scope properly and give some examples of what I'm exactly looking for, it could work. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30074502#30074502 for the transcript, with Rand saying "Policy on list questions is that they're OK provided they're finite and well scoped" I think I managed to get the scope down fine

Comment: It *is* a bit more specific - asking for particular stories which follow a particular mode of storytelling.  It's more like story-identification at that point, maybe?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo [tag:episode-identification] questions are more agreed upon, right?

Comment: I couldn't say.  I don't spend enough time here to be sure.  I'm just trying to help bolster your case cause I gave you an answer. ;)  Either way hope you enjoy your trip!

Comment: I voted to close because this is a) awfully subjective and b) even if it was better scoped, it's a list/recommendation question covering potentially *dozens* of episodes.

Comment: @valorum Why would it be subjective? I'm asking "where does the Doctor beat the monster of the week on his own through talking?" Is that subjective?

Comment: @Nzall - Well, for starters at least one of your examples has the assistant play a part, which you've completely disregarded ("*with a little help of Danny Pink.*"). How much involvement can be disregarded?

Comment: @Valorum All Danny Pink did was catch the remote and control the cybermen. the Doctor still managed to connect the dots himself and knew what to do. More importantly: assuming I can clarify to the point where the list can be objectively toned down to "a few dozen episodes", would that list be an acceptable answer?, the "who got drunk in Harry Potter" and the "Who died in Harry Potter" lists were also a few dozen long each.

Comment: @Nzall - Yes, and you'll note (from the comment chain below my answer) how much discussion we ended up having over something even as simple as what constitutes "*being drunk*". That question, by comparison, is as clear as a crystal bell compared to yours. Also, the Potter question only covers 7 books, not 50+ years worth of TV shows.

Comment: @Valorum I've edited the question, slightly altering the scope to give a better idea of what I'm looking for and making it clearer what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, it's certainly shorter. No less off-topic, but at least it takes less time to read and find that out. Basically it boils down to *"These are some episodes I liked. What episodes can you recommend that are similar in some way?"*

Comment: @Valorum No, because the question is not asking for recommendations, but for classification of **all** Classic Who episodes (a finite list, which is never going to change) into which satisfy the OP's criteria and which don't. I'm not going to hammer it open, but my personal feeling is that **this question should be reopened**.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It's certainly a lot cleverer than most recommendation questions because they've at least tried to fold it into a "what episodes have x" type question and the OP seems super-motivated, but that doesn't change the nature of the beast.

Comment: -1 because I don't understand the question. What does it mean to "deconstruct" the bad guy's plans? The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction) was unhelpful, to say the least.

Comment: @user14111 I have edited the question. Basically, deconstruction as used with regards to literature means that you methodically take apart a certain aspect of the story, explain what's wrong with the plan and essentially say "your plan sucks, why not give up?" TVTropes has a better explanation of what i'm looking for that I'll edit into the question: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheReasonYouSuckSpeech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find, I think, that classic who doesn't quite fit so neatly into your classification, but that said, here are one or two episodes, per Doctor, that may fit your request.  If you disagree, well, I tried:

First Doctor
- The Keys of Marinus
- The Time Meddler

Second Doctor (Limited selection due to the lost episodes)
- The Tomb of the Cybermen

Third Doctor
- The Ambassadors of Death (somewhat borderline here)
- The Three Doctors (a must see as it features pretty much only the Doctor, the Doctor, and the Doctor)
- Planet of the Spiders (Ok this one isn't really a fit for what you're asking but on the other hand if you never see this you miss a tremendous story)

Fourth Doctor
- Robot
- Terror of the Zygons
- The Brain of Morbius 
- The Invasion of Time (including extensive internal TARDIS scenes)
- City of Death (hope you know who Romana is)

From here on I'm having a harder time thinking of any given situation where just the Doctor is primarily responsible.  His companions become more competent, less slack-jawed ignorant, starting with the Fourth Doctor, and so the Doctor often only plays part of the role - a catalyst but not necessarily the cure.

Fifth Doctor - 
- The Kings Demons

Sixth Doctor
- The Two Doctors

Seventh Doctor
- The Greatest Show in the Galaxy

Comment: 2nd - The War Games; 3rd - Colony in Space / The Mutants; 4th - Genesis of the Daleks / Destiny of the Daleks; 5th - The Visitation; 6th - The Mark of the Rani / Attack of the Cybermen; 7th - Remembrance of the Daleks / Curse of Fenric / Survival; 8th - The TV Movie

Comment: I don't think the TV movie really qualifies with the OP's request.  As I recall, the Doctor was pretty helpless w/o his companions.  And Genesis of the Daleks - quite a lot of Davros plans were foiled by Sarah and Harry, not the Doctor.

Comment: There was at least one scene with the Doctor explaining the Master's plan to Grace ("He wants to steal my body..." also "This world will be turned inside out...").